# Dispatch inside componentWillMount showing async behaviour

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

i am writing a React code for a online course project, and is stuck on a dispatch action

```
class Burger extends Component{

 componentWillMount(){
  this.props.init() //dispaching action so to make a boolean variable "Purchased" false
 }

 render(){
  console.log(purchased)  //it is still true ;
 }

}
```

So my concern is basically that even passing through *componentWillMount* the **purchased** variable is still true . The value of my variable do change but after the rendering of component.

> i am basically getting a type of **asynchronous** type of behaviour with *dispatch* in which my variable value change but after render function

Please help

**P.S.** i have my redux store,actions,reducers all are configured correctly. I just want to know why it didn't work.

**Here is my reducer for that**

```
case (actionTypes.PURCHASE_INIT) :{
            return{
                ...state,
                purchased : false,
            }
        }
```

Comment: Move your init call function to componentDidMount hook.

Comment: componentWillMount is known for resulting in unexpected behavior and its use is no longer encouraged. For more info see https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillmount

Comment: check mapStateToProps function whether it receive updated variable

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things i can suggest:-

1. Please use Redux dev tools in chrome and see what is happening.
2. Dont use componentWillMount rather use componentDidMount and then check once you dispatch this action, see whether state get updated and print the same variable on mapStateToProps in your container component and then print the same in render function so that you track it sequentially